# Error during compiling

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am receiving this error when i compile "main.cpp: In constructor ‘TicTacToe::TicTacToe()’:
main.cpp:38: error: array used as initializer
" Any clues? thanks.

```
class chicken {
public:
    chicken() : board("123456789") {};



private:
    char board[10];
    char player; // Switch after each move.
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize the array like that. Instead use **strcpy**.

```
TicTacToe() {
      strcpy(board,"123456789") 
}
```

Or use std::string to make use of constructor initializer.

```
class TicTacToe {
public:
    TicTacToe() : board("123456789") // Ok
    {};

private:
    std::string board ; // Changed to string type. There is no good reason to use 
                        // character array when string type is available.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

"123456789" has 10 characters because there is a NULL at the end.

Comment: now im getting main.cpp: In constructor ‘TicTacToe::TicTacToe()’:
main.cpp:38: error: array used as initializer